# Need an optimized mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, datatables, serverside-datatable

[image: table to [optimize]]

Above is my mysql table.
The column `dvr_id` has the values of same table primary key `dealer_visit_id` and `dvr_id` is nullable column. 
I need to fetch all records of dealer_visit table which is a simple thing. But the catch is that, along with all records, I need a **"count"** of `dvr_id` column corresponding to each record being fetched.

for example: If I want to fetch record with `dealer_visit_id` **2660**, I'll write query as

```
select col1,col2,col3, (SELECT count(dvr_id) from dealer_visit  where dvr_id=dealer_visit_id GROUP BY dvr_id as totalDVRs) 
 from dealer_visit;
```

Need something like this but the query is too slow when I try to fetch 1000+ records..Its taking more than 9 seconds to fetch records. When I remove the **COUNT** query, it fetches 1000+ records within 1-1.5 seconds.

How can I optimize the query so that I get records along with count of rows depending on 1 column value?

I hope am clear in my question.

Edit 1: Suppose the dataset is as below:
[image: Example Dataset]

Now If I fetch record with **dealer_visit_id** 33, I should get 
row with **dealer_visit_id** 33 **ALONG WITH count(dvr_id) having 33 as in example dataset** 
So expected output for the above dataset should be:

Expected output for select query (with count of dvr_id column having 33 as value) of dealer_visit_id = 33

```
|   dealer_visit_id   |   employee_id   |   originally_created_by    |   dealer_id   |   COUNT(dvr_id) |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    33               |     20          |         20                 |      226      |    6            |
```

The Count(dvr_id) = 6 is important thing in my question that am trying to fetch quickly. You see here, the result is of row with dealer_visit_id=33 and count of something that can be called its **sub rows** or related rows which is 6 according to example data set.

**Below is output of Explain table**

```
Field                   Type                          Null    Key     Default  Extra           
----------------------  ----------------------------  ------  ------  -------  ----------------
dealer_visit_id         int(10) unsigned              NO      PRI     (NULL)   auto_increment  
employee_id             int(10) unsigned              NO              (NULL)                   
originally_created_by   int(10) unsigned              YES             (NULL)                   
dealer_id               int(10) unsigned              NO              (NULL)                   
dvr_id                  int(10) unsigned              YES             (NULL)                   
dealer_emo_id           bigint(10) unsigned           YES             (NULL)                   
department              enum('SALES','ASSURED','EM')  YES             (NULL)                   
dvr_type                enum('FOLLOWUP','DVR')        YES             (NULL)                   
present_members         varchar(4096)                 YES             (NULL)                   
visit_date              date                          NO              (NULL)                   
location                varchar(45)                   YES             (NULL)                   
overall_remarks         text                          YES             (NULL)                   
active                  tinyint(1)                    YES             1                        
is_complete             tinyint(1)                    YES             1                        
is_closed               tinyint(1)                    YES             (NULL)                   
is_data_migrated        tinyint(1)                    YES             0                        
report_close_date       datetime                      YES             (NULL)                   
report_completion_date  datetime                      YES             (NULL)                   
followup_number         int(11)                       YES             (NULL)                   
total_followups         int(11) unsigned              YES             0                        
last_modified_date      datetime                      YES             (NULL)                   
autosave_time           datetime                      YES             (NULL)                   
create_date             datetime                      NO              (NULL)                   
updated_by              int(10) unsigned              NO              (NULL)                   
nearest_visit_date      date                          YES             (NULL)
```

Comment: count(dvr_id)   group  by dvr_id  return always 1  ... try explain better add  a clear data sample and the expected  result

Comment: You should not use sub-queries or join to get this type of Data.
Please Specify what technology are you using, so that its will be easier to get the data with an optimized way

Comment: I mentioned MYSQL database in my question. Even in screenshot. So its obvious that its mysql query.
@bhuvneshpattnaik

Comment: Aren't you using any specific object oriented language or scripting language like `JS`, `PHP` or `JAVA`.
Do not use subqueries or JOINs to optimize, rather take help from languages which will be easier to optimize the whole code base and data retrieval time.

Comment: @bhuvneshpattnaik I am using Java but I am not at all in need of doing this all alone inside Java code. Because i posted here some simplified thing from the actual requirement and table structure. In real project, the data comes from multiple tables and not just 1. Need this to be done in mysql only.

I need it for Server-Side datatable. Hope now you are clear why I need this to be done in MySQL itself.

If I do it all in Java code, I'll need to manually handle to datatable's total count of records and every single thing it displays. If you've worked with server-side datatable, you'll know

Comment: @scaisEdge I have updated my question with example dataset.

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance ALWAYS require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: @Strawberry Why show create table is needed in this case?
The question is How do I optimize my subquery so that I can get results including "COUNT" faster than it is taking time right now

Comment: Show create table is needed to know which indexes you have. Explain is needed to know how MySQL is currently executing the query. Also, although you may like images of data, other people like to see table structures as they are used to it (e.g. as code). Or they want to play with the code and can then simply use this to create the tables and run/test/modify your code. Additionally, your description does not match your query. If you use "where dealer_visit_id=2660" (with dealer_visit_id the primary key) you will not get 1000+ records in 1.5s, just one. Do you maybe execute it 1000 times?

Comment: the thing you wanted cannot be optimised in another way with mysql instead of let data be arranged in code, server-side datatable, Nowhere, it is written that everything needs to be done in single query, yes everything needs to be done in single instance but not in single query. Making all in single query, You are only making your queries heavy on SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is fine, I see no issue with your queries. I made more complex than that, with millions of records

I think it comes down to INDEX your columns properly.

use EXPLAIN to study if index is used.

Comment: Query is fine as it loads correct data BUT too slow as well. What it is doing is it is executing the subquery for each record 
So If I have 1000 records to fetch, query will be executed twice so 2000 times for select records

Comment: added in question

Comment: That is describing a table.  But try this....
 SHOW INDEX FROM [table_name]  ;

because i want to see the current indexes of your table;

Comment: Adding index on "dvr_id" column improved speed drastically. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

First, your query is not correct in multiple ways:

- The `from` in the subquery refers to a column, not a table.
- The `group by` could return multiple rows.

I think you want:

```
select dv.*,
       (select count(*)
        from dealer_visit dv2
        where dv2.dvr_id = dv.dealer_visit_id
       ) as totalDVRs
from dealer_visit dv;
```

For performance, you want an index on `dealer_visit(delaer_visit_id)`.

Assuming `dealer_visit_id` is unique, then in MySQL 8+, you should instead do:

```
select dv.*,
       count(dv.dvr_id) over (partition by dv.dvr_id) as totalDVRs
from dealer_visit dv;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error in question about incorrect `from` table name. Edited the question now.

And yes you are right with what I want to fetch. 
But the query is too slow. But adding index on "dvr_id" column improved speed drastically.